# for loop in java for avoiding to play audio file at once

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
 public static void Audio2(String filename) {
    // String filename = "chaithurest";
    if (filename.equals("test1")) { 
        String test1= System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//test1.wav";
        filename = test1;
    }
    else if (filename.equals("test2")) { 
        String test2=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//test2.wav";
        filename = test2;
    }
    else
        filename  = filename;
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filename ));
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This code is working only if I am passing one file name. If I am passing multiple file names by calling this program both audio files are playing at the same time. Is there any possibility where I can play one by one.

I am calling this audio2 file as below

```
if (!ARRAY.contains(filename)) {    
    Audio2(filename);
}
```

Comment: use wait() or delay to stop for few seconds

Comment: I don't get it. How can you pass `2` file names to a method that accepts only one?

Comment: i tried this .. but it is playing only first file not the second one :(

Comment: if array doest contain the file name which already it will call the audio by passing the file name.. if array contains more than one value then its causing the issue

Comment: As suggested by @Prashant, one option is to put in a wait().  The issue with this is that you need to know how long to wait before the program runs. This would work fine for your test (for example, you know that test1.wav is 20 seconds long) but won't work for unknown files.  What you're really going to need, with your current setup, is an event mechanism that signals when one file is finished playing and you can move to the next.

Comment: Can you provide more context around the call to `Audio2()`? and is the `AudioPlayer` class the one from the package `sun.audio`?

Comment: is that possible after passing file name can we use some thing like for loop  so that we can execute one by one.. if so how? any ideas

Comment: You did not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `sun.audio.AudioPlayer` provides a `stop(InputStream)` method. In order to prevent to play several files you can add some logic in `Audio2()`, for instance:

Add an `audioStream` member to the class, and set it when you play:

```
 // In the class
 static AudioStream currentAudioStream = null;

 public static void Audio2(String filename) {
    //...
    try {
        if (currentAudioStream != null) {
           AudioPlayer.player.stop(audioStream);
        }
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filename ));
        currentAudioStream = new AudioStream(in); // <= set member
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
    }
    //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Audio2(String filename) {
// String filename = "chaithurest";
if (filename.equals("test1")) { 
    String test1= System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//test1.wav";
    filename = test1;
}
else if (filename.equals("test2")) { 
    String test2=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//test2.wav";
    filename = test2;
}
else
    filename  = filename;
try {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filename ));
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
     AudioPlayer.player.join(6000);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```